# React JS Filed to compile scss file, ошибка при подключении scss, как подклчить scss файл React JS

Tags: reactjs, scss

Ошибка

```
./src/Test/Test.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--7-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-5-4!./src/Test/Test.scss)
SassError: Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
        on line 1 of D:\Site\nodejs-task1\front-react\src\Test\Test.scss
>> 

   ^
```

Test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Test.scss';

const Test = () => {
  return <p className="test">Test</p>
}

export default Test;
```

Test.scss

```
.test {
  color: red;
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Test from './Test/Test';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


ReactDOM.render(
  <Test />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Что я делаю не так? Уже часа 4 гуглю, все ответы перепробовал, по нескольким статьям пытался подключить scss.

Comment: Что странно, если просто изменить расширение на .sass и поменять расширение при импорте, будет работать

Answer (score 0):

мда. Помогло удаление node_modules и установка `npm install`